# Filter list of string with contains and sorted by contains position

Tags: android, sorting, kotlin

I have list of string say

`var list = mutableListOf("clock", "kite", "rekt")`

Now, I need to filter list according to character. Currently I am filtering by:

`list.filter { it.contains("k") }`

It gives me result

`[clock, kite, rekt]`

But this is where I have problem, I want to filter the list and also sort by its character position and expected result is

`[kite, rekt, clock]`

where the character "k" comes first is first at the list and so on.

I am confused what to do. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sort it you have to use a `Comparator`. Comparator contract is described here in method compare [here](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-comparator/#functions)

*Compares its two arguments for order. Returns zero if the arguments are equal, a negative number if the first argument is less than the second, or a positive number if the first argument is greater than the second.*

So in our case we take two strings `a` and `b` and we look at what position the k is present.

**Example:**

```
a = "clock" // position of 'k' is 4
b = "kite" // position of 'k' is 0
```

Comparing those two `4 - 0 = 4` results in a positive number which means first argument is greater than the second.

```
a = "kite" // position of 'k' is 0
b = "rekt" // position of 'k' is 3
```

Comparing those two `0 - 3 = -3` results in a negative number which means first argument is less than the second.

**Code:**

```kotlin
var list = mutableListOf("clock", "kite", "rekt", "abcd")
list.retainAll { it.contains("k") }

// Ascending Order
list.sortWith(Comparator {a, b -> a.indexOf('k') - b.indexOf('k')})
println(list) // [kite, rekt, clock]

// Descending Order
list.sortWith(Comparator {a, b -> b.indexOf('k') - a.indexOf('k')})
println(list) // [clock, rekt, kite]

// Cleaner and more concise syntax thanks to @Tenfour04
list.sortWith( compareBy { it.indexOf('k') } )
list.sortWith( compareByDescending { it.indexOf('k') } )
```

Comment: If you want to filter in place, you need to use `retainAll` rather than `filter`. In the code above, the `filter` call creates a new list, which is promptly lost to the GC, and the `sortWith` call is done on the original list.

Comment: You can also use `compareBy { it.indexOf('k') }` instead of the `Comparator` call for a more concise expression. And there's also `compareByDescending`.